# Issues setting up mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a php script that (in theory) connects to a database. The issue is that when I try to test my script in http://phptester.net/ it tells me that said credentials are wrong.

[image]

I am fairly new to this whole php and mysql set up but this is what I know thus far:

1. I have a domain registered @ godaddy.com with hosting (obviously)
2. I used their Database Interface to create my first database (I called it myProfile)
3. I also used their interface to create a user and added that user to the database with all its privileges

**Here is where the issue lays:**
I go to Databases link in my cPanel page and see my database WITH my user and you can see its privileges:

[image]

[image]

Now, I go to **phpMyAdmin** in **godaddy** and I find that there is *indeed* the myProfile database but I can't find the user I created.

[image]

I see a user that I never ever seen before but no matter what I do in phpMyAdmin I can't ADD, CREATE, GRANT PRIVILEGES or do anything user related. I even tried looking up in a query to see if the one I created on the interface shows up. But nothing works!

[image]

[image]

Can anyone help me with this conundrum?

Comment: If you're having issues/questions about GoDaddy's services (which this question seems to be about), I would recommend contacting them instead.

Comment: Refresh privileges and as said above, contact their support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your host likely doesn't accept incoming connections from anywhere but 127.0.0.1. Even if it does, it shouldn't accept those requests unless they're encrypted.

Therefore, PHPTester.net fails - not by any deficiency, just because Godaddy is using default/recommended/smart security settings to disallow these remote connection attempts.

Why not try testing the database connection by opening a browser window pointed at the connection page you're showing us?

Comment: Thank you! The support team at GoDaddy had to finish setting up permissions for me. Like I said in my question I am fairly new at this but I'll get to where I need to be. Thanks again and everyone who helped! You all rock!

Comment: You're welcome. Just know that your credentials are probably going across the internet in plain text from. Do NOT store anything valuable in this database. Once you're comfortable with your tests, you should change the database user password and cease using phptester.net. Nothing against phptester, it's just an insecure setup. :)

Answer (score 0):

I dont really get lucas's answer but after creating a user you have to explicitely assign the user to the database.

[image: Here is how its done from CPANEL -> Databases -> MYSQL Databases]

Comment: yeah I did that immediately after but still nothing. Thanks, though

Comment: He could assign the user to the database, but since he was trying to test his PHP by using a 3rd party website to connect to his database, there needed to be an additional step to allow for this.

Comment: I myself own two servers and haven't had the problem, when connecting from one server to the other with php, going from a mysql table to a postgres table, never had a problem. thats usually why specifying a port is standard practice in php-sql code, because usually you do connect to another computer and dont just specify a localhost.